# Are handlers asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, handler, monolog

I'm using Monolog to log in to Symfony. But I'm logging in elasticsearch with Monolog. I am using Handlers of Monolog for this.

```
    $this->logger = new Logger('name');
    $this->logger->setHandlers([
        new ElasticSearchHandler(
            $this->elasticaClient,
            [
                'index' => 'my_index',
                'type' => 'my_type'
            ]
        )
    ]);
```

My question is, is this process asynchronous or synchronous? is to control performance or not. By default handlers, are asynchronous or synchronous?

Are handlers like threads or something like that?

Comment: I'm also wondering this.  I'm not using Elasticsearch, but Loggly.  The Loggly website has a Wizard that guides you through adding a new logging source, which includes a question "I prefer logs sent asynchronously without blocking my app" and then offers the Monolog library as an option.  However from what I can see in the LogglyHandler source code it uses Curl in a blocking fashion, so sending each line of logging will block until it returns.  It seems the blocking behaviour is different for each Handler.  Anyone know of a good discussions anywhere analysing this?

Answer (score 1):

Each of this processes is synchronous. Logging is just an insert transaction if you are using database storage that not seriously influent to performance.

Handlers are like instances of objects for data handling and storing behaviors.